# Solve T(n)=T(√n)+ n using substitution method

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

I am confused how to solve this recurrence equn. after a particular step (step involving ? in the picture)

(Plz help me solve the question with same method which I have used and correct if any of the steps are wrong!)

Attached is what I have done so far..

[image]

Comment: Please do not delete your question if someone has answered it. Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @Gilles But I wanted a to know the steps after my steps ...not the ultumate answer...I even posted a separate question for this..but people down voted.. ( https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2863839/what-is-the-sum-of-series-n-1-2k-n1-2k-1-n-1-2k-2-dotsb?noredirect=1#comment5908867_2863839)   guess I had to go for the offline means...

Comment: Now you have deleted the question on [math.se].  Are you trying to hide your using the internet to solve this exercise?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus haha why would I hide! Anyways..what's the purpose of posting the question which no body is answering but rather down-voting , also it was the same question just asking the sum of series which I am stuck on.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, 
$$
T(n) = n + \sqrt{n} + \sqrt[4]{n} + \cdots,
$$
and the number of terms is at most $\log \log n$. Hence
$$
n \leq T(n) \leq n + \sqrt{n} \log\log n.
$$
This implies that $T(n) \sim n$.

Comment: sir, what will be the sum of series from 2nd term n^(1/2^(k-1)) up to the last term n

Comment: It has no nice closed form expression.